# Apple Music API Limitation

Tags: ios, swift, apple-music, apple-musickit

I am planning to use the Apple Music API (Apple Music Catalog) to search through songs in my app. By reading the docs and stack overflow I know that there is a rate limit however I am wondering if this limit affects  all users using the app or per user base.

In the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/getting_keys_and_creating_tokens#3001403) it says 
"If you are requesting anything from the Apple Music Catalog, the request will hit Apple's cache first, which doesn't check your rate limit. If you are requesting anything from a personalized endpoint, calling it will always check the rate limit."
Does this mean that Apple Music Catalog does not have a rate limit?
It may be a silly question but I'm very confused...

Answer (score 0):

> You receive the Too Many Requests (429) error when you exceed your request capacity as determined by the server.

I think this line means that API has certain rate limit only to prevent `bad Joes` from exploiting their servers.

However, I have found this on Apple developer forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/110457

[image]